# object return empty description in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

hello I am doing something like this.

```
NSString * fblink=[dm.commonDataArray valueForKey:@"fb_link"];

if(![fblink isEqual:[NSNull null]]||![fblink isEqualToString:@""]||![fblink length]<=0)
{
    [fb_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_user_fb"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fb_button addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(buttonFBTouch:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}else{
    [fb_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_fb_red_gray"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

when I type `fblink` in my log it says `(lldb) po fblink
<object returned empty description>` But still my if condition become true and go inside ratherthan going to else part.

How can I overcome this problem?I dont want to execute my if condition true part if its return empty description. How can I checked this condition? Please help me
Thanks

Comment: i think you have to use && instead of || .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your if condition. `fblink` is `nil`, you are checking nil is equal to `[NSNull null]` so this case fails and you invert the result so it becomes true and goes inside of this if case.

If we expand your if case it becomes:

```
if(![nil isEqual:[NSNull null]]||![nil isEqualToString:@""]||![nil length]<=0)
{
}
```

Which becomes

```
if(!false||!false||!true) // which evaluates to true, you are using ||, so if any one condition is true, it will go inside of the if case
{
}
```

You need to change that if case to:

```
if([fblink isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ![fblink length]<=0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try.....

```
 if(![fblink isEqual:[NSNull null]]&&![fblink isEqualToString:@""]&&![fblink length]<=0)
{
    //your code here .......
 }
 else
    {//your code here  ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `fblink` is not `null` but its an empty string. Thus your `![fblink isEqual:[NSNull null]]` is becoming true and your `if statement` is getting executed. Only check it with the following condition:

```
if(![fblink isEqualToString:@""]||![fblink length]=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the || (or) condition to  &&(and) condition.

Try this:

```
    if(![fblink isEqual:[NSNull null]]&&![fblink isEqualToString:@""]&&![fblink length]<=0 )
    {
        //your code
    }
    else
    {
       // your code
    }
```